# How can I execute rgvim from inside a daemonized process?

Tags: linux, vim, file-descriptor

I have some ruby code, it has the following

```
system("rgvim " + MY_FILE)
```

This works fine from the terminal but if I run this code as a rack application using systemd, the system call fails to work.  I get the message:

```
Dec 06 14:40:54 mypc config.ru[10211]: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Dec 06 14:40:54 mypc config.ru[10211]: Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

I think this is because the daemonized process does not have access to the file descriptors.

**EDIT**  Some commenters asked for more specific details of my use case.  Here goes:  I'm trying to start a rack-based ruby app with `systemd`.  The rack app has the above system call in the code, and works fine when I run it from the terminal using

```
rack config.ru
```

However, when I start it with systemd, as described above more generally, the rack app does not have access to the right file descriptors.  It seems to me like it should be somehow possible to map the current X display and/or file descriptors from `systemd`

Comment: Which terminal do you expect `vim` to be attached to when you call it from your daemon?

Comment: For that matter, what do you even expect vim to **do** when called like this?

Comment: Deamons typically run with stdio using /dev/null. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, @duskwuff that should say *gvim*.  The error message says Vim, but you get the same thing with gvim.  Should make better sense now.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's `vim`, `gvim`, `rgvim` or any other variant, running as a daemon means it doesn't have access to a controlling terminal or your X display (which, in a addition, may be locked or logged out, or not even running). So the real question is, what are you hoping/trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's possible, but you would first have to lessen the security of you current X session with the xhost command.

Comment: @Keith Inadequate X permission seems like it could be an issue, but unrelated to the fact that vim can't access std{in,out}.  Do you have a more concrete suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Vim is an interactive text editor, it is not meant to be used without an attached terminal; that's where the warnings come from.

You can try running Vim in *batch mode*; cp. `:help -s-ex`, like this:

```
vim -T dumb -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
 -T dumb            Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
 -n                 No swapfile.
 -es                Ex mode + silent batch mode  -s-ex
                    Attention: Must be given in that order!
 -S  ...            Source script.
 filespec           The file to operate on.
```

Comment: I am trying to launch an instance of gvim in the running X session.